# Table Highlighting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/nabosh/pen/pjRjmX)

**Background:** I have a basic table that is using a [jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/ndp/align-column) that actually allows you to center numbers around a decimal point in a table. It does this by adding an additional td with a class of "added" (represented by + in the table) - this works great except I am not sure how to make it so I can hover over the last "added" td (represented by [+] in the table) and have it highlight the same as happens when hovering over [7] in the table

This is the code which I believe needs modifying:

```
$('td').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var rule = RULES[id];
  if (rule == null)
    return;

  $highlightCells = $('.default-highlight').removeClass('default-highlight');
  rule.forEach(function(id) {
    $('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('id') === id;
    }).next().andSelf().addClass(HIGHLIGHT)
  });
});
```

**Possible Solutions:** I am thinking that I should be able to make a variable like:

```
var prevId = $(this).prev().attr("data-id");
```

and then something like,

```
if(prevId == RULES[id]){$highlightCells...}
```

but I haven't been able to get that approach to work.

Hopefully the Codepen at top is helpful.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated, apologies if this is obvious, I slept on this, but haven't gotten it to actually work yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with a solo if statement. I am sure this isn't the best solution, but it is working...so, that is enough for me for the moment.

Thanks for reading.

[LINK TO WORKING CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/nabosh/pen/wKgmMq)

If statement and some surrounding code (can all be seen in Codpen):

```
/*HIGHLIGHTING ON MOUSEENTER*/
$('td').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var prevId = $(this).prev().attr("data-id");
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var rule = RULES[id];
  var rulee = RULES[prevId];

  if(typeof prevId != 'undefined'){
    $highlightCells = $('.default-highlight').removeClass('default-highlight');
    rulee.forEach(function(prevId) {
      $('td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('id') === prevId;
      }).next().andSelf().addClass(HIGHLIGHT)
    });
  }

  if (rule == null)
    return;

  $highlightCells = $('.default-highlight').removeClass('default-highlight');
  rule.forEach(function(id) {
    $('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('id') === id;
    }).next().andSelf().addClass(HIGHLIGHT)
  });
});
/*END*/
```